# "Unable to establish SSL connection" on WSL Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect WSL Ubuntu with CLion to be able to compile C/C++ programs in Windows 10. I am following the steps given in:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html?

However, when using the script to configure SSL, I get the message from: 'Unable to establish SSL connection!

Does anyone have a solution or do you know why this happens?

[Screenshot Bash Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnkPY.png)

Comment: In which step did you see that error? Can you provide a screenshot or something related to that error?

Comment: Hi @Biswapriyo , error is in step 4: Configure and run open ssh-server. I already added an image...

Answer (score 1):

you need to generate a ssh keygen and make some amendment to sshd config file , i can use the Clion WSL after making modifications to the config file with ubuntu 18.04LTS

RSA Key call in root with command ssh-keygen must be stored in the /etc/ssh directory

Make sure the Port 2222 or whatever port is also without # in the file located in /etc/sshd_config

Listen address suggest to alter to 127.0.0.1 for local host

In the authentication section

PermitRootLogin yes

Add

AllowUsers Your_username

UsePrivilegeSeparation no

PubkeyAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication yes

Login to root sudo su

sudo service ssh --full-restart

you must also ensure whatever port assigned is allowed by windows firewall which can be  verified  with  netstat -a  to confirm the port assigned is in deed open